# Will modifying shared methods change the class that reference them?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I'm wondering what will actually change a class, in the sense that **serialized objects** of this class will no longer be recognized.

If the class has **reference to shared methods** of another class. Will changing such shared methods also change the classes that reference them?

And what about changing **extension methods** to custom classes, will that impact the class "signature", if that's an appropriate term?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking here. How about a short code example showing what you're contemplating.

Comment: I can't exemplify this in code. It's simply a question about the class definition. If I change a class, objects of this class that was serialized before the change, may produce an exception if I try to load/read them into a program build with the new/changed class. I'm simply asking what type of changes will create such exception. Any change? changes only to properties and fields? Changes to methods, reference to static methods of other classes? Extension modules?    Which of these will change the class definition, and which will not?

Comment: Changes to extension methods should have no effect on the class at all, since those extension methods aren't part of the class interface. They're just syntactic sugar that makes them *look* like part of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good reference for this is [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752.aspx) on MSDN. In short, changes to Shared (static in C#) *methods* do not affect the deserialization of an object:

> - Never remove a serialized field.
> - Never apply the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to a field if the attribute was not applied to the field in the previous version.
> - Never change the name or the type of a serialized field.
> - When adding a new serialized field, apply the OptionalFieldAttribute attribute.
> - When removing a NonSerializedAttribute attribute from a field (that was not serializable in a previous version), apply the OptionalFieldAttribute attribute.
> - For all optional fields, set meaningful defaults using the serialization callbacks unless 0 or nullas defaults are acceptable.

*As a minor aside*: changes to certain special methods related to serialization could affect deserialization. But you'd be making a conscious decision to change those.

Comment: Thanks! I was not even aware of these attributes existence, so I will read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

Serialized objects change when the ***data*** changes. References to methods are never serialized; they are part of the code rather than the data.

Comment: I think that's not exactly what I'm asking. I'm asking what type of code changes to my classes will leave previous serialized objects not to be recognized by the current program build. I'm trying to understand how to code my classes for avoiding the need to run custom update code on archived data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing binary serialization, changing both private and public properties of the class that gets serialized will "break the interface".  If you're doing XML or JSON, changing of public properties will alter how its serialized.  Methods do not get serialized, so you can change those and it will still work (so long as you don't change the signature).